# Count image amount via ID tag

Tags: html, image, tags

Pretty basic question.

How simple would it be to give an image an ID tag (obvs not that part..) and count how many of the images are on the page with that tag?

Comment: Better add class and `$(".image").length`

Comment: ID tags should be unique to a page. So your count would always be one.

Comment: `function countImagesById( id ){ return 1; }`

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, they are all on 1 page :)

Comment: Then you should be using a class not ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ID`'s should be unique on a page, you should be using a `class` instead:

`<img src="/img/src.jpg" class="my_image" />`

You could then use javascript to count the number of elements

`var imgCount = document.querySelectorAll('.my_image').length;`

the variable `imgCount` now contains the number of `img` tags with the class `my_image`

DEMO

```js
var imgCount = document.querySelectorAll('.my_image').length;

alert(imgCount);
```

```html
<img src="/img/src.jpg" class="my_image" />
<img src="/img/src.jpg" class="my_image" />
```

If you absolutely must use the same `ID` on multiple elements (maybe these are generated by some third party scripts or CRM?) the above does work (in Chrome at least). Demo below.

```js
var imgCount = document.querySelectorAll('#my_image').length;

alert(imgCount);
```

```html
<img src="/img/src.jpg" id="my_image" />
<img src="/img/src.jpg" id="my_image" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just realized it already has a class attached! :S Should I just use that or can they have more than one class?

Comment: You can have as many class' as you like. Just space separate them `class="class1 class2 classN"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using query better to used `.length`.

```
<div id="some_id">
    <img src="some_image.png">
    <img src="some_image.png">
    <div class="another_div"></div>
    <div class="another_div"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var x = $("#some_id img").length
  alert(x);
</script>
```

Check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/btLgwe7x/).